# Gantt charts in plotly

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, gantt-chart, highcharts-gantt

Hi I have created a Gantt chart with simple code that I find online:

```
# gantt is just my pandas dataframe

import plotly.figure_factory as ff
fig = ff.create_gantt(gantt, colors = ['rgb(170, 14, 200)', width = 742, height = 580)
fig.show()
```

For some reason when I run this the output seems fine except the xaxis dates are missing a lot of months and the ending is cutoff
so it looks like this:

```
Apr 2024 Jul 2024 Oct 2024 Jan 2025 Apr 2025 Jul 2025 Oct
```

can anyone help with this?

Comment: You could try the [plotly Python forum](https://community.plotly.com/c/plotly-python/5)

Comment: @DarrylG why? Is the one I am using not supposed to work or what? How exactly do you use that?

Comment: It is not specific as to how you expect the x-axis time series to be displayed. At the same time, some sample data might help me understand a little better. I will share a reference on how to handle [Gantt charts](https://plotly.com/python/gantt/) and [time series](https://plotly.com/python/time-series/).

Comment: @bernando_vialli as r-beginners pointed out, some sample data would help us reproduce the error you're seeing, but if your data is private, maybe you can provide some dummy sample data. or you could provide more details about the dataframe such as the column names and column data types

Comment: with a small dummy data set, i can't reproduce the behavior you're seeing, so you'll have to help us out a bit with more information